# AWS CLI - S3, why do I need to specify a region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So my bucket `Alpha` is in a region called `REGION1`.

My bucket `Beta` is in a different region, let's call it `REGION2`.

I go into my EC2 instance, and use this command:

`aws s3 cp s3://Alpha/meh.txt ./meh.txt`

It works! So far so good. It works perfectly.

But, when I do this command:
`aws s3 cp s3://Beta/qwe.txt ./qwe.txt`

I get the following error message:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request
```

The error above can only be fixed if I specify the region flag. Why is that?
Because I thought bucket names are unique regardless of region, so why should I need to specify a region?

Is there a way to stop this from happening without specifying a region? Maybe a special policy or something?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your choice of default region (`~/.aws/config`) what makes your use of "Alpha" work?

Answer (score 0):

Only AWS knows the answer to this. AWS could remove this requirement, but I guess they want you to be explicit.

It would be simple enough to do automatically. When the client gets a request to a bucket a central lookup service could determine the bucket region and send the request there. That however creates a single point of failure. You could work around that by running the lookup service in every region, and having all the endpoints in the client, but that's more code, more configuration, more services to run, more services taking CPU.

If they didn't want to run a lookup service then the requests would have to go via a central point, proxied to your region. That takes CPU and bandwidth.

It's probably easier and more efficient to specify the region than the other options.

Comment: Actually, you can ask any regional endpoint for the correct region for any bucket, because all of the regions know about what's in the global bucket directory... but doing that, or using redirects, or proxying, would be very inefficient for round-trip, bandwidth, and latency, and could have jurisdictional/legal implications when traffic transits other countries.  The problem here, as @HåkanLindqvist suggested in comments, is that a region almost certainly *is being specified*, via config, and it is not the correct region.

Comment: I was talking about the difference between providing a directory, which as you've pointed out they do, and proxying traffic to the correct region.

Comment: Sorry, @Tim. I could have been clearer. My intention was that you were correct about the inefficiency of proxying, and to mention that there are other complications of that as well.  While it's possible to access the directory, that, too, is inefficient... but I believe the cli will quietly do it anyway if you don't give it a region explicitly or in config.  I never configure aws-cli with a region, and always specify it explicitly, since it keeps me mindful about where my assets are.